# what is the most old safari version which is used so far by users?

Tags: browser, safari

I am not familiar with Safari but I am developing website and I want to know from what safari version I should start to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see Safari browser statistics here - http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_safari.asp. Given that Safari 4 had a 0.1% market share in August of this year, I would say that it is safe to assume that it is the lowest version worth supporting. As supporting evidence, as of June of 2011, Safari 3 was down to a 0.0% market share - someone out there might be using it, but not many at all.